# Sonatype Nexus server on localhost doesn't cache artifacts

Tags: maven, nexus

I have installed nexus-2.11 on my 64-bit localhost Windows. I am running `mvn` within `build.xml` in Eclipse via ant-tasks. I have set the nexus server in `.m2/settings.xml` as the main mirror:

```
<mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</mirror>
```

When running `mvn` commands, dependencies are resolved and it is shown in the log that they are being downloaded from the Nexus server. The problem is with the Nexus cache: Nexus does not cache anything. I mean the `sonatype-work` folder is empty and all artifacts are inside `.m2`.

Logging in the admin panel, I can see the complete index for artifacts, but no jar files or metadata are inside `sonatype-work`. (After downloading all artifacts, I want to put contents of `sonatype-work` into the main server which is offline because of security reasons.)

What may have caused this?

Comment: does the Nexus process (Jetty, I believe) have write access to the folder `sonatype-work`?

Comment: Yes. I also tried to run it as administrator and even moved to another drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `sonatype-work/README.txt`, I set the environment variable `PLEXUS_NEXUS_WORK` to the path of `sonatype-work` and then, Nexus started caching into the work folder.

> The location of the individual work folders may be overridden using environment variables. For example, the Nexus work location can be defined with PLEXUS_NEXUS_WORK. If it is not defined, then this default is used.

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert something like this in the `profiles` section of your `settings.xml`?

```
    <profile>
        <id>company-nexus</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>  <!-- use a not existing URL!! -->
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
```

This causes maven to look in the `mirror` definition.

Comment: Yes I did. Messages like `Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/...` are shown when running commands. So, It _does_ look at the mirror definition.